# ManyToMany relationship in "hibernate" does not insert values into the join table when initializing the application

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I got a lot of answers and advice, tried changing my code according to these tips.
But, unfortunately, these tips helped only partially.

Now, when creating a new project and creating a new user, I can add the desired user to the set of projects, and the required project will be added to the set of users.

But the relationship between the desired project and the desired user will not appear in the project_user table.

Please help find the answer.

Entity Project

```java
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "project_users",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "users_id"))
    private Set<User> projectUserSet = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "project_task",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id"))
    private Set<Task> projectTaskSet = new HashSet<>();

    public void addUserToProject(User user){
        this.projectUserSet.add(user);
        user.getUserProjectsSet().add(this);
    }

    public void addTasksToProject(Task task){
        this.projectTaskSet.add(task);
        task.getTasksProjectSet().add(this);
    }

    //constructors, hashCode, equals, toString
}
```

Entity User

```java
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projectUserSet", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Project> userProjectsSet = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_task",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "users_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "task_id")})
    private Set<Task> userTasksSet = new HashSet<>();

    public void addTaskToUser(Task task) {
        this.userTasksSet.add(task);
        task.getTasksUserSet().add(this);
    }

    //constructors, hashCode, equals, toString
}
```

project and user initialization

```java
        Project project1 = new Project("Project1", "Project1");
        User user1 = new User("User1", "User1");
        project1.addUserToProject(user1);
```

Answer (score 2):

With code shown below, table `project_user` is populated, verified using H2 console. In order to avoid stack overflow, I had to modify method Project#addTaskToUser as shown below.

Please note that only code relevant to the question, is included.

Normally, issue should be described by some tests. In this case, I added a `CommandLineRunner` that runs at startup.

`CascadeType.ALL` is not recommended for many-to-many relations, hence I changed this in code shown below.

Tested using H2 in-memory db.

Project class

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "project_users",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "users_id"))
    private Set<MyUser> projectUserSet = new HashSet<>();

    public void addUserToProject(User user) {
        this.projectUserSet.add(user);
    }
}
```

Project repo

```
public interface ProjectRepo extends JpaRepository<Project, Long> { }
```

User class

```
// cannot use @Data here because it will cause cyclic ref and stack overflow when accessing userProjectsSet
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="projectUserSet")
    private Set<Project> userProjectsSet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

User repo

```
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}
```

In app class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner run(ProjectRepo projectRepo, EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {    
        return args -> {   
            var testUser = new User();
            testUser.setFirstName("first-name");
            testUser.setLastName("last-name");

            var project = new Project();
            project.setName("project-name");
            project.setDescription("project-description");

            project.addUserToProject(testUser);
            projectRepo.save(project);    

            // get saved user and print some properties
            var userInDb = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().find(User.class, testUser.getId());
            System.out.println(userInDb.getFirstName()); // prints "first-name"
            System.out.println(userInDb.getUserProjectsSet().size()); // prints "1"
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice on using CascadeType.
In this case, you have made minimal changes that almost exactly duplicate my code and, therefore, do not solve the problem in any way. Everything works in H2. It's the same in PostgreSQL. But join tables are never populated with values